# MongoEngine _types and _cls fields

Tags: django, mongoengine

Why does mongoengine add **_types** and **_cls** fields to every document of a collection.
Both of them are a (key, value) pair and both of them contain the name of the document's model class. The only difference is **_types** value is a list and I assume it can have multiple model class names if there is involved some inheritance.

However the question is: why do I need them to exist in every document within a collection when all the documents will have the same values for both fields?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mongoengine allows Document Inheritance.  When defining a class a meta attribute `allow_inheritance` is used to allow subclassing this particular class.
The `_cls` and `_types` fields are used to identify which class the object belongs to.

Consider a document called `User` used to store users' information:

```
class User(Document):
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
    # stores information regarding a user
```

Now consider a document called `StackOverFlowUser` : this document is inherited from the `User` document and saves some StackOverflow-related information for a user:

```
class StackOverFlowUser(User):
    # stores StackOverflow information of a user
```

For both these document classes, mongoengine will use the same collection named `user`.  No matter which document object you create, it will be stored as a document in this collection.

To differentiate to which class the object belongs to, `_cls` and `_types` fields will be used.

For a `User` object:

```
{
    ...
    '_cls' = 'User',
    '_types' = ['User', 'User.StackOverFlowUser']
}
```

For a `StackOverFlowUser` object:

```
{
    ...
    '_cls' = 'User.StackOverFlowUser',
    '_types' = ['User', 'User.StackOverFlowUser']
}
```

If you are sure that a document is not going to have a sub-class document, then set `allow_inheritance` to `False` and mongoengine will not save `_cls` and `_types` fields for that document.

Comment: Please note that _types will be going in 0.8