# MongoEngine object returning empty queryset when collection has entries in mongo database

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I'm trying to return a queryset using MongoEngine 0.8.6 in Django 1.8.12.

The model it's called **Job** and I already have some objects in the MongoDB collection.

Here the catch, in Django's shell the following retrieves no results:

```
> Job.objects.count()
> 0
```

However if I access the Mongo collection directly, the actual count is given:

```
> Job._get_colletion().count()
> 50
```

By checking the `_meta` attribute of the MongoEngine object, I made sure it was pointing to the correct MongoDB collection.

But here's the funny part. I am not able to replicate this behaviour in my other environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I manage to find a solution.

The problem was because I had the attributes 'allow_inheritance=True' when it should be 'False'. You can understand it better by reading this

[MongoEngine _types and _cls fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824569/mongoengine-types-and-cls-fields)

Comment: what if youre trying to use inheritance to build your models?